# "say" vs "tell"

Tags: difference

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/say_1):
**(1)** *The incident **says** an awful lot about his character*.
my variant:
**(2)** *The incident **tells us** an awful lot about his character*.
What's the difference between "say" and "tell" here?

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/say_1):
**(3)** *The museum's architects have managed to **say** something about our national story*.
my variant:
**(4)** *The museum's architects have managed to **tell us** something about our national story*.
What's the difference between "say" and "tell" here?

---

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tell):
**(5)** *The doctor **told me** to stay in bed*.
my variant:
**(6)** *The doctor **said to me** to stay in bed*.
What's the difference between "say" and "tell" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three pairs of sentences have the same meaning, assuming that in (3), the context is what the museums architects have communicated through the architecture of the museum building itself, rather than through some verbal communication not mentioned in the context.

For the first two pairs, while "say" often has the meaning of "speak words", it can also have the meaning of "communicate", "reveal", "show", etc., just like "tell" does.

For the last pair, while "tell" usually indicates communication of information, in the structure *[ "tell someone to" + infinitive ]* it becomes a command, and so does *[ "say to someone to" + infinitive ]*.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that "tell" takes a direct object, the person who is being told.

"Tell" also has the specific idea of "communicate information", whereas "say" is about making words with your voice, but it also has extended sense of broadcasting information, ideas, speculation, poetry and son on.

You can say to me "I wonder if the moon is made of green cheese."  But this utterance does not communicate information, so you can't tell me this.

The examples are valid both as "say" and "tell".  However the direct object is unnecessary in the first examples so "say" would be preferred.  And in the last example the object is required, so "tell" is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the grammatical requirements of the two verbs: they have pretty much the same meaning.

*Say* requires the thing said (whether a quotation, a clause, or occasionally a noun phrase) as a direct object:

> He said "I'm coming".

> He said he was coming.

> He said a prayer.

It does not require a recipient or listener: one may be given, with a *to* phrase, but this is an adjunct (optional extra information) not a complement (required by the verb), and so the ditransitive pattern is not possible:

> He said a prayer to God.

but not

> *He said God a prayer

*Tell* in its usual sense is ditransitive (has both the direct object and the indirect as complements), so the ditransitive pattern is possible:

> He told the message to me.

> He told me the message.

It can also be used intransitively, with the direct object unexpressed; but the indirect object (the recipient or listener) is required:

> He told me.

but not (normally)

> *He told the message.

There is another meaning for *tell*, "relate a story". In this sense, it is not like the usual *tell*: it requires a direct object, and does not require an indirect one:

> The book tells the story of a little girl called Janet.

There is also a third meaning of *tell*, meaning "instruct", or "command", and that obligatorily takes a recipient and a *to-* infinitive clause, in the ditransitive construction:

> He told me to go home.

In summary ("[]" means optional; "*" means ungrammatical):

> Say  *direct-object* [ "to" *indirect-object*]

> *Say *indirect-object* *direct-object*

> Tell *indirect-object* [*direct-object*]

> Tell *direct-object* to *indirect-object*

and in the sense of "tell a story" only:

> Tell *direct-object*.

and in the sense of "instruct" only:

> Tell *indirect-object* *to-infinitive-clause*.

Comment: I have noticed in casual speech, especially in the US, people say things like 'Tell him "No"', or 'I told him "Goodbye".

Comment: Yes, @MichaelHarvey. I didn't specify what syntactic items the direct object of _tell_ can be: you're pointing out that a direct quotation is possible in colloquial use.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer has nothing to do with those examples I asked to consider. Everything you wrote is that information I had already known before.

Comment: @Loviii, I began with "they have pretty much the same meaning". In your first two examples the only difference is that the recipient "us" is expressed in one case and not in the other. The third case is a little different, and I admit that I missed that, because it is a third meaning of "tell": "instruct" or "command".  I have added that to my answer.